# How to tell Facebook to update my site's pages in Facebook cache more frequently?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph

Authors writing for our *website A* are also handling promotion of articles they wrote - they share these articles on Facebook by simply <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> article's URL and hitting Publish post button.

They told me that most of the time they are having problems with sharing these articles in a way that the article's image is appearing only partly or is not appearing at all.
They also said the only way to fix it was to put article's URL into the Facebook Debugger to force an update of article's page in Facebook’s cache. So for every 5 articles, they have to debug 4 of them.

But I wouldn't be writing if it was so simple. The problem is, authors writing for our other website - *website B* have never encountered a similar problem. So I wonder what might be causing this to happen.

I know it could be caused by Facebook crawling *website B* faster and more often than it is crawling *website A*, in that case I would like to know why is that so and how to fix it.

Comment: Have you tried sharing it with a dummy parameter?   Instead of sharing `/my-artcle` try sharing `/my-article?refresh=19382`. Facebook may have to re-fetch for every dummy parameter.

Comment: Do websites A & B use the same  platform for posting articles?  I find I have to use the debugger for almost every new post via WordPress.